# how to remove unnecessary chars from date command output in python

Tags: python, linux, shell, command

I am new to python. Forgive me if it's too simple. I want to extract only date using `date` command in python

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["date", '+%m/%d/%y'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output,err = p.communicate()

print (output)
```

Now this is printing

```
b'05/14/13\n'
```

How to remove the unnecessary '\n' and `b` at start.

Comment: Have you considered using  **import datetime** **print datetime.date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%y')**  ?  Just saying ...

Comment: @tink: Is there some particular value to using `datetime` as opposed to `time` in this case? It seems more complex.

Comment: @tink how can i achieve same for time also. I am trying datetime.time.strftime('+%H:%M:%S')

Comment: for time I used `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: @kampu: it is; but it's OS independent. Big bonus.

Comment: @tink: Do you mean that `time` is not available on some platforms? [That is incorrect](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/time.html).

Comment: @kampu  Ummm .. no, where did you get that idea from?  The date command, and its invocation used, are unix/linux specific.

Comment: @tink: I got that idea from the fact that I asked you "*Is there some particular value to using __datetime__ as opposed to __time__ in this case*" and you answered "*it is; __but it's OS independent__. Big bonus.*".  Seems like you didn't actually read my question fully...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomas's answer is correct, but I feel more explanation is necessary.

I always `.decode('utf8')` the result of `p.communicate()` or `check_output()` et al. This is because **stdout/stdin is always opened in binary mode**, unless you explicitly provide a file handle, so you always receive/send **bytes**, not *str*.

In this case, I suggest just using `check_output(['date','+%m/%d/%y'])` rather than creating a Popen object which you then basically throw away :)

So, I would suggest rewriting this to:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(['date', '+%m/%d/%y']).decode('utf8').rstrip()
print (result)
```

On a more meta level, there is a question of whether you even need to use `subprocess` for this task.
After all, there is `time.strftime()` for formatting dates/times. This:

```
import time
print(time.strftime('%m/%d/%y'))
```

achieves the intended effect of your entire program in a much simpler way.

Also from [tink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394729/tink)'s comment:

```
 import datetime 
 print datetime.date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

Comment: Thanks. I will refer this for future. I have used strftime func

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> str(b'05/14/13\n').rstrip()
'05/14/13'
```

Speed comparisons:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(r"b'05/14/13\n'.decode('ascii').rstrip()")
0.7801015276403488
>>> timeit.timeit(r"str(b'05/14/13\n').rstrip()")
0.2503617235778428
```

Comment: There is always a question in my mind when I see a bare `str(some_bytes_object)` -- what encoding is being used? (The 'system default encoding', aka `sys.getdefaultencoding()`?).

Comment: For curiosities sake, here are some more numbers: on my system, from a cold start, `..decode(..)..rstrip()` takes 1.36967, `str(..).rstrip()` takes 1.15654, and my own favored option `str(..,'utf8').rstrip()` takes 1.33954 -- it's interesting how much slower it is with the encoding parameter explicitly specified.

Comment: @kampu that's interesting (thanks for running these tests). I like your favorite best for readability, though if performance was an issue it seems `str(...).rstrip()` is best

Comment: Thanks. I will use it for future.

Answer (score 1):

`b` means it is a binary string, you can get a unicode string by `output.decode('ascii')`. To get rid of the trailing newline:

```
output = output.strip()
output = output.decode('ascii')
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will refer this for future